# Gráficos con Dyango, imposible!

Tags: javascript, django

estoy trabajando con Django desde hace poco y todo iba medio bien hasta que me tocó mostrar una gráfica, las dudas las solventaba con ChatGPT, que mal o bien me ayudaba. El problema viene cuando quiero implementar un gráfico, me traigo una variable 'context.datos_diaros' que contiene un Formato Json (día, horas, salidas), pero como uno trabaja en el servidor y el otro en el cliente me dice que no está definida la variable. Probé con promesas pero no lo consigo, se me ocurrio meter los datos en el HTML:

```
<div id="context-datos-diarios" style="display: none;">{{ datos_diarios|safe }}</div>
```

Con este Javascript:

```
<script type="module">
// Función para obtener los datos
function obtenerDatos() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const datosDiariosElement = document.getElementById('context-datos-diarios');
        if (datosDiariosElement) {
            const datosDiarios = datosDiariosElement.textContent.trim();
            if (datosDiarios) {
                resolve(JSON.parse(datosDiarios));
            } else {
                reject('No hay datos disponibles.');
            }
        } else {
            reject('No se encontró el elemento de datos.');
        }
    });
}

// Función para crear y mostrar el gráfico
function crearGrafico(data) {
    const chartElement = document.getElementById('chart1');
    const chart = createChart(chartElement, { width: 800, height: 400 });
    const lineSeries = chart.addLineSeries();
    lineSeries.setData(data);
    chartElement.style.margin = "0 auto";
}

// Esperar a que se cargue el DOM
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Obtener los datos
    obtenerDatos()
        .then((data) => {
            // Una vez que se obtengan los datos, crear y mostrar el gráfico
            crearGrafico(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Manejar cualquier error, como datos no disponibles
            console.error(error);
        });
});

</script>
```

y luego lo dibujo así:

El caso es que me dice que no es una cadena válida, no se porqué, ya que si le hago un lazo **for** en una tabla la rellena sin problema, entiendo que le paso un diccionario, pero Javascript debería tomarlo como JSON o tendría que hacerle pasar por alguna función que la formatee?

Seguramente será muy sencillo, pero no tengo el conocimiento suficiente aún.Me vendría bien un poco(bastante) de asesoramiento.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola Nelson... No me quedó claro... cuál es **exactamente** tu pregunta?

Comment: Hola Arriel, gracias por contestar, al final era que le estaba pasando un diccionario que no contenía el formato JSON adecuado. Un saludo!!